# Parameters not working in Stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

When I set parameters for month, year, and report source they don't seem to have any impact. I'm still getting all sales when running the procedure. Can anyone see whats wrong?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ddsDiscount] 
   @month INT, 
   @year INT, 
   @report_source nvarchar
AS 
   SELECT 
      isa.identifiers                           AS ISBN, 
      isa.sales_date                            AS DATO,
      isa.quantity                              AS ANTALL,
      bk.title                                  AS Tittel, 
      BV.name                                   AS BUTIKK, 
      BB.name                                   AS Forlag, 
      COALESCE(id.sales_price, isa.sales_price) AS SalesPrice 
   FROM   
      book_sales AS isa 
   LEFT JOIN 
      discount AS id ON isa.identifiers = id.identifiers 
                     AND isa.sales_date BETWEEN id.from_date AND id.to_date 
                     AND Month(isa.sales_date) = @month 
                     AND Year(isa.sales_date) = @year 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      books AS BK ON BK.book_id = isa.book_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      store AS BV ON bv.store_id = isa.store_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      publisher AS BB ON bb.publisher_id = bk.publisher_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      book_contributor AS BC ON BC.book_id = isa.book_id 
                       AND isa.report_source = @report_source
```

Comment: First: what **database** are you using? SQL is just the query language - not clear **which** database that speaks SQL it is you're programming against. Second: `nvarchar` **without** a length gives you a parameter (in SQL Server) which is **exactly 1 character** long - is that your intention?? I would recommend to **always** specify a length! Use `nvarchar(20)` (or whatever is appropriate) instead of just `nvarchar`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. Ahh the nvarchar is supposed to be (255). Still not working tho.

Comment: See my answer - you're checking for those `@Month` and `@Year` parameters in the wrong place (they have nothing to do with the JOIN to the discount table - put them in a normal `WHERE` clause!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting the check for the conditions in the wrong place:

```
   FROM   
      book_sales AS isa 
   LEFT JOIN 
      discount AS id ON isa.identifiers = id.identifiers 
                     AND isa.sales_date BETWEEN id.from_date AND id.to_date 
                     AND Month(isa.sales_date) = @month 
                     AND Year(isa.sales_date) = @year
```

Here, those conditions (defined by `@YEAR` and `@MONTH`) are **only** evaluated if there **is** a discount - if there is none, those conditions will **not** be applied.

Also: those conditions really don't have anything to do with the JOIN to the `discount` table - they **only** refer to the base `Book_sales` table. You should remove those from the JOIN condition and put them in a regular `WHERE` clause instead:

```
 SELECT 
      isa.identifiers                           AS ISBN, 
      isa.sales_date                            AS DATO,
      isa.quantity                              AS ANTALL,
      bk.title                                  AS Tittel, 
      BV.name                                   AS BUTIKK, 
      BB.name                                   AS Forlag, 
      COALESCE(id.sales_price, isa.sales_price) AS SalesPrice 
   FROM   
      book_sales AS isa 
   LEFT JOIN 
      discount AS id ON isa.identifiers = id.identifiers 
                     AND isa.sales_date BETWEEN id.from_date AND id.to_date 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      books AS BK ON BK.book_id = isa.book_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      store AS BV ON bv.store_id = isa.store_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      publisher AS BB ON bb.publisher_id = bk.publisher_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      book_contributor AS BC ON BC.book_id = isa.book_id 
                       AND isa.report_source = @report_source 
   WHERE
      Month(isa.sales_date) = @month 
      AND Year(isa.sales_date) = @year
```

Comment: @Lebowski: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters only affect selection from discount table. Move the parameters to where clause.